# How to pass model value in url action to controller function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, model-view-controller

I am displaying the value in the hyperlink. Now when I click on the particular link I want to pass the same SeriesName in my Controller.

```
foreach (...){
<a href="@Url.Action("Series","Tools",new { catalogSeries = "dataSeries.SeriesName" })" class="tag1">@dataSeries.SeriesName</a>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle as the below

```
@foreach (var item in items){
    <a href="@Url.Action("Series","Tools",new { catalogSeries = @item.prop1})" class="tag1">@item.prop1</a>
}
```